# Why is there a tower of subfields between $F$ and $KF$ such that each step is cyclic of prime order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Can somebody explain the theorem $7.2$ in Lang's Algebra

[image]

Questions:

$\bullet$ What does it mean ''Let $m$ be the product of all primes unequal to the characteristic dividing the degree $[K:k]$'' really all primes, that is infinity ?

$\bullet$ Why is there a tower of subfields between $F$ and $KF$ such that each step is cyclic of prime order ?

Comment: Lang's algebra book is a torture

Comment: Only finitely many primes divide the degree $[K:k]$, so there's no infinite product here. Your second question is answered in the quote: $KF$ is solvable over $F$, meaning its Galois group is a solvable group, and the meaning of solvable group is that the successive quotients are all cyclic of prime order.

Comment: @GerryMyerson and that is (degree) to ensure the separability ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Why do we take the product of those primes , to ensure that $F$ is abelian over $k$ ?

Comment: If $k$ is any field, and $\zeta$ is any root of unity, then $k(\zeta)$ is abelian over $k$. You might find it easier to follow the proof the way it is set out in Stewart's Galois Theory text.